# Vba Cons Numbers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vba

I want to make a list of cons numbers(ex. 1,2,3...) in field calculator (VBA).
When I am putting for example:
(dim d d=[field]+1).
The result is all my fields are =1.
How to solve this arc map (vba).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to populate a field with a sequential series of numbers? If so look at [Calculate Field Examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000). An example is provided in Python:

> Calculate a sequential ID or number based on an interval.
>
> *Expression:*
>
> ```py
> autoIncrement()
> ```
>
> *Code Block:*
>
> ```py
> rec=0
> def autoIncrement():
>  global rec
>  pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
>  pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
>  if (rec == 0): 
>   rec = pStart 
>  else: 
>   rec = rec + pInterval 
>  return rec
> ```